# jQuery serializeJSON and selection list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application, jsonserializer

I have a form that include text input , range slider and simple  selection lists :

```
<label for="select-choice-1" class="select" id = "selectionString" >select field:</label>
<select id="a"></select>
<label for="select-choice-2" class="select" id = "selectionString">select profession:</label>
<select id="b"></select>
<label for="select-choice-3" class="select" id = "selectionString">select experience (in years) :</label>
<select id="c"></select>
```

The data that the selection list gets comes from a javascript file :

```
var fields = {"HT":"HI-TEC","MK":"marketing","FE":"Finance&Economics"};
```

My problem is that serializeJSON() function dont include the selection list inside(all other fields are OK ) , i can add this manually but someone have a butter way to do it ?
the clicklistener starts after all the fields are selected .
the serialize function :

```
var workerInfo = $( "#workerForm" ).serializeJSON();
```

Comment: Are the select-element rendered with options (and selected) before you serialize the form?

Comment: Yes , the serialize function starts by onclick listener , when the form is completed.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400010/jquery-serialize-not-processing-value-of-dropdown-list